# Calculating pairwise Euclidean distance of 3d points between all the rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 200000 rows. The dataframe looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A-0001',21.8,3.2,6.6,'B-0001',2,8,9],['A-0002',21,3,6,'B-0002',1,8,8],['A-0003',8,9,2,'B-0003',7.64,5.5,12.4]])
df.columns = ['pointA',"A_x","A_y","A_z",'pointB',"B_x","B_y","B_z"]
```

That is :

```
pointA   A_x     A_y  A_z    pointB   B_x    B_y    B_z 

A-0001   21.8   3.2   6.6    B-0001    2     8      9
A-0002    21     3     6     B-0002    1     8      8
A-0003    8      9     2     B-0002  7.64   5.5    12.4
```

"A_x","A_y","A_z" is the coordinate of point A, and "B_x","B_y","B_z" is the coordinate of pointB

I want to add a new columns"distance" of df,  df["distance] is the distance between pointA and point B of each row.

What is the fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to do this in a fully vectorized manner:

```
df["distance"] = np.sqrt((df.A_x - df.B_x)**2
                       + (df.A_y - df.B_y)**2
                       + (df.A_z - df.B_z)**2)
```